# Need some clarification on Java threads: start() and run()

Tags: java, multithreading

According to the StackOverflow answers, `start()` creates a thread and executes the code in this new thread and `run()` executes the code in the current thread without creating any - as if it was a `Runnable`

But the docs, if I understood them properly, say that `start()` initializes a new thread an then, if you want to re-execute your code in the same thread, you call `run()`

Which one is right?

UPD

Okay, looks like calling `run()` manually is not a good practice and is at least useless. Are there some good ways to call the code in `run()`? Say, I have a relatively slow action that is required frequently, one instance at a time - what then?

Comment: Where do you read that? A quote might be helpfull to clear up your confusion. Start() actually starts the parallel execution of this new Thread, run is just the method that is called. Where this method runs depends on from which Thread you call it. Start() automatically calls it from the new Thread that was started.

Comment: `run` is called by `start` and exists only to be overriden.

Comment: if you call `run` then `run` will be executed by same thread not by `new Thread`. same thread can not be restarted again, if it has finished its job. and start method will create new thread and will call `run()` method internally using newly created thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As quoted, *neither* of them is right.

`start` doesn't create or initialize a thread. It *starts* a thread. From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start--):

> Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine calls the run method of this thread.

The thread is *created* and initialized by calling the `Thread` constructor, which naturally you have to do prior to calling `start`. (That's the "external myth," anyway; I'd have to check the JVM spec, but I suspect it would probably be *valid* for a JVM to defer actual creation of the OS thread until/unless you called `start`.)

In the normal case, you never call the `run` method of a `Thread` instance directly. Instead, you start the thread via `start` and the JVM schedules a call to `run` on the actual thread assigned to that `Thread` instance. If you call `run` directly, it gets called on the thread you're using to do that, which probably isn't the one assigned to the `Thread` instance.

You may find the [Java concurrency tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) useful.

---

Re your comment below:

> And how to re-execute the code in `run()`? Restart the thread or have some infinite loop with a `boolean` value controlling the execution?

The latter, but not an *infinite* loop, a loop with a termination condition. From the `start` documentation:

> It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.

So once `run` returns, that's it, you can't keep using the thread. Instead, you have the thread not return from `run` until its work is done. If you want to keep it around waiting for work, it should wait on a semaphore of some kind that you can signal from outside the thread, to wake it up to do some work.

A subsection of the tutorial above talks about one way to do that with [Guarded Blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html) using `wait` and `notify`/`notifyAll`.

---

Here's a simple example where every call to `System.out.println` prints the name of the thread on which the call was made so you can see which thread does what:

[**Live Copy**](http://ideone.com/uhF9Yg)

```
class Example
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Thread t= new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": Running run");
            }
        });
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": Running main");
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": Calling t.start()");
        t.start();
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": Calling t.join() to wait for thread exit");
        try {
            t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": Calling got InterruptedException");
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": Program complete");
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
main: Running main
main: Calling t.start()
main: Calling t.join() to wait for thread exit
Thread-0: Running run
main: Program complete
```

Note that our main thread just called `start`; then the JVM set things up so that `run` would be called on the thread we'd created.

Comment: Okay. And how to re-execute the code in `run()`? Restart the thread or have some infinite loop with a `boolean` value controlling the execution?

Comment: @Alex: In general, don't re-execute the code in `run`. The thread should run until its work is done, after which the thread has served its purpose. What's the use-case where you think you need to re-run it?

Comment: start() method causes the thread to  go into the ready state.

Comment: The thing is I have a relatively hard task required to be executed frequently - so I moved it to another thread. I doubt that people create a new thread each time they need to execute the same task. Or do they? There must be some good practices for such issues

Comment: @Alex: I updated the answer to better address your earlier comment; I think it probably addresses that one as well. You have the thread enter an efficient wait state, waiting on a semaphore of some kind (there are lots of kinds), and wake up to do its work.

Comment: Good, it's clear now. Also, the tutorial will be handy. Thank you!

Comment: The Javadoc for `start()` doesn't say that it creates the new thread, but that's how I would implement it.  Creating a thread is expensive, and there's no reason to do it until `start()` has been called.

Comment: Just read what you said about the "external myth".  IMO that myth only helps to keep newbies confused about the difference between a `Thread` (i.e., the Java object) and a _thread_ (i.e., the operating system object).

Answer (score 3):

Your confusion probably comes from the ambigous use of the terms *thread*, *create* and *initialize*. Without specifying what they exactly address its easy to misunderstand, because there are multiple concepts that the term *thread* is used to describe.

On one hand, there is the Thread object (that is created through new Thread(...) constructor). Thats *not* the thread in terms of actually executing anything. Its just a *facade* for the threading mechanism that implements a standardized API to interact with the OS/VM.

Just creating a Thread instance is basically *not any different* from creating any other java object. Nothing happens yet that has anything to do with actually adding a thread to the OS thread scheduler.

The thread on the OS side is actually created in a (private) native method start0(), the start() method performs some sanity checking, then calls start0() to actually create an OS-Level thread.

So the general order of actions is:

- Create and Initialize a Thread-Object

  - Nothing out of the ordinary happens yet
- You invoke start() on above Thread-Object

  - Delegates to native code to *create* an OS-Level thread. Entry point for the OS-Level thread is Thread.run() on the java side.
  - Executes Thread.run() on the new thread (default implementation of run delegates to the Runnable the Thread object was created with, or does nothing if no Runnable)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the main difference between start() and run():

> [Thread#start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start()): when program calls start() method the Java Virtual Machine calls the run method of this thread.
>
> [Thread#run](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#run()): If you call run() method directly code inside run() will execute on current Thread.

Comment: what did you say about Thread#start is wrong. because the start() method doesn't create a thread. it causes the thread to  go into the ready state.

Comment: @Win.Ubuntu updated my answer. thank you for correcting me.

Comment: To say that there is a difference between `start()` and `run()` is misleading.  They're both just methods.  They're both called in the same way that any other method is called.  They both just do what their code says to do.  In the case of Thread.start(), it's code causes it to create and start a new thread.  But what does `run()` do? Don't ask me!  Ask the person who wrote it!  Thread.start() is the method that the library provides for your code to call to start a new thread.  Whatever.run() is the method that _you_ provide for the library to call _in_ the new thread.

Comment: @Win.ubuntu Why do you think Thread.start() does not create a new thread?  If you were implementing the Thread class, when would _your_ implementation create the new thread, and why?

Comment: @jameslarge it doesn't create a new thread. but it creates a new execution thread. Try this:  `Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {for` `(;;)System.out.println("Hello...!");});  thread = null; thread.start();`
`// thread= null;`

Comment: @Win.ubuntu, OK, I see.  What you call an "execution thread" is what I call a "thread."  What you call a "thread" is what I call a "`Thread` instance" or a "`Thread` object".  Whatever.  What's important is teaching the newbies that the two _concepts_ are different regardless of what we choose to call them.  B.T.W., I'm not sure why you wanted me to "try this" (i.e., apply `.start()` to a null reference.)  Obviously, that won't do anything but throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Just to demonstrate that `start()` method doesn't create thread :-)

Answer (score 1):

> if I understood them properly, say that start() initializes a new thread an then, if you want to re-execute your code in the same thread, you call run()

This is incorrect. You need to understand that every Java program begins it's execution with the *main* thread. In other words, when you run a Java program that has a `main` method (e.g java MyProgram), a new execution stack is created with the `main` method at the bottom of this stack.

If a program creates a `Thread` instance in the `main` method and calls the `start` method on the thread instance, a new execution stack will be created with the `run` method at the bottom of the stack. You will now have two execution stacks. One with the `main` method at the bottom of the stack and the other with the `run` method at the bottom of the stack. These two stacks can complete their execution in parallel.

On the other hand, If you call `run` on a thread instance in the `main` method instead, it will simply be called in the same execution stack as the `main` method. A new execution stack will not be created. Therefore, calling `run` on a thread instance is as good as calling any other method on any other object and has no special meaning.